# What information are cloned when an application is created from Zygote process?

Tags: android, process, clone

I'm aware of the concept that android clones a new process from Zygote during each application start - what information are cloned from zygote. It's unclear for me what information (whether information related to few system components are cloned).

1. Why does it really clones from Zygote process?
2. What information are cloned from Zygote process?
3. Why does Zygote needs to be a parent process for each application process?

Though it's android's decision to do it in this way - would like to know whether there is any explicit technical reasoning which people are aware of for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zygote process preloads all the android frameworks into memory. This way, when forking a new (app) process from zygote, it has the frameworks already loaded, which speeds up application start-up. Linux' copy-on-write mechanism for memory pages even avoids duplication of the framework code in memory. Zygote also sets up various security context settings after forking to ensure all processes have the appropriate context  (esp. SELinux).

Comment: What would happen when Zygote loads the framework classes (that class creates instances of some other class within it's static block) - what will happen to these instances when the Zygote process is cloned as application process.. Will the application process be able to access the instance created by zygote?

Comment: Will there be any shared memory between zygote and application process? If yes, will application process is allowed to write in it? How this sandbox environment looks like?

Comment: I don't think any instances are created or statics initialized by zygote. Just the (byte)code is loaded. Don't know about shared memory, but that seems unlikely, as it would be quite a security risk. IPC generally happens via binder.

Comment: One more simple question, since bulk of framework jar is present at the class path of my application will it increase the memory used by an application? Will the classes get loaded on demand?

Comment: I think the memory for the framework code will only be consumed once for each device, as the respective pages will be automatically shared between processes. Linux handles this automatically and transparently.

Comment: Can you explain (or) share me some reference to understand how the pages are shared between processes?

Comment: For example [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=368650&seqNum=2)